# DJango NoModuleFoundError

Tags: python, django, importerror

I'm getting **ModuleNotFoundError** in my Django project, I have done a lot of research on similar posts and made project relevant changes, but no luck! and unable to resolve the error, so it made me post this.
Project structure Screenshot -> [Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaSkB.png)

Stacktrace for reference.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/web_app/web_app/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from web_app.mob_apis.views import login
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web_app.mob_apis'
```

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @John, I have set it to my current dir path but no luck.

Comment: "current dir path" is not specific.  What is the actual value of `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @John when I print echo $PYTHONPATH its empty and when I print using print(sys.path) its `['', '/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7', '/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Users/prithvi/pyhtonprojects/DjangoProjects/doc_app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
from mob_apis.views import login
```

instead of

```
from web_app.mob_apis.views import login
```

in your 
doc_app/web_app/web_app/urls.py file